# How do I stop flask to convert a list containing data in json format into json again?

Tags: python, json, sas, flask-restful

I am building a flask application that reads a SAS dataset from  a remote linux server and returns response in json format. I am executing the following sas command using paramiko ssh_client to read the sas data into json format. Basically in the sas_command, I am using "PROC JSON" that coverts sas dataset into json output. I am redirecting the output of "PROC JSON" into STDOUT and then reading it into python list.

My question is why do I see the "\" in my final output. Looks like Flask converts the  output of sas_command which is already in json format, into json format one more time . How do i get rid of the additional characters in my final output. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

sas_command =  "sas94_u8 -STDIO <<<\"OPTIONS NOFMTERR; PROC JSON OUT = STDOUT pretty; EXPORT '" + dir_name + "/" + file_name + "'; WRITE OPEN OBJECT; WRITE CLOSE; run;\" 2>/mydev/null"

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(sas_command)
result = []
out = stdout.readlines()
result1 = list(map(lambda x: x.strip("\n"), out))
return result1

My final flask response is in this format:
[
    "{",
    "  \"SASJSONExport\": \"1.0 PRETTY\",",
    "  \"SASTableData+dataset\": [",
    "    {",
    "      \"varseq\": 1,",
    "      \"sasname\": \"ADSNAME\",",
    "      \"scope\": \"G\",",
    "      \"notuse\": \"\",",
    "      \"type\": \"C\",",
    "      \"label\": \"Dataset Name\",",
    "      \"lbl_ana1\": \"\",",
    "      \"lbl_ana2\": \"\",",
    "      \"outform\": \"8.\",",
    "      \"codlst\": \"X_NM\",",
    "      \"methtyp\": \"derived\",",
    "      \"deri_way\": 1,",
    "      \"method\": \"=%_some_method\",",
    "      \"vartype\": \"\",",
    "      \"var_link\": \"\",",
    "      \"adslcore\": \"\",",
    "      \"deri_txt\": \"Name of the data set.\",",
    "      \"comment\": \"\",",
    "      \"core\": \"Req\",",
    "      \"adamnote\": \"\",",
    "      \"mand\": \"M\",",
    "      \"source\": \"C\",",
    "      \"status\": \"A\",",
    "      \"ret_reas\": \"\",",
    "      \"cor_reas\": \"\"",
    "    },",
    "    {",
    "      \"varseq\": 2,",
    "      \"sasname\": \"SID\",",
    "      \"scope\": \"G\",",
    "      \"notuse\": \"\",",
```

Comment: Have you tried using json's loads function?
`from json import loads`
`result2 = loads("".join(result1))`

Comment: Hi @Magnetron. I haven't tried it yet, will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @Magnetron, I am getting the following error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 163831 (char 163830)

Comment: It's having trouble decoding the JSON - that function basically treats the input string as json and attempts to convert it into python objects. So, the next step might be to get a smaller example (not 163831 characters long) and try it on that. The flask server isn't converting it to JSON again, just simply treats it as a string... \ used as an escape for the double quotes which are already used as actual quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will try to run the function on a smaller string may be.

Comment: Thanks @Magnetron for your suggestion. The error mentioned in my previous comment was coming because of the header information in incoming json string. After I removed it, it worked perfectly. Thank you !!!